# How can I add a header to my JSON output table?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I'm trying to add a header to this JSON output table, but I have no clue how to do that. This code gives me a table populated with the data returned from the database and puts it in a table format as structured by the `<td><tr>` tags. The problem is that I need a header for the table and I don't know how to get that part coded. Any ideas?

```
function renderSearchResults( results, domNode ) {
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    if (results.length === 0) {
        domNode.innerHTML = 'No results matching your search.';
        return;
    }
    // loop to print the JSON in a table format
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        console.info(result);
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        result.ContractId +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.ContractTitle +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Terminal +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Cabinet +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Section +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Folder +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Sheet +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Consult +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Location +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Active +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Theme +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Construction +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Subtheme +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.AsBuilt +
        "</td><td>" +
        result.Year +
        "</td><td>" +
        "<a href= " + result.Path + " target=_blank>" + "Binder" + "</a>"
    } );

    out += "</table>";
    domNode.innerHTML = out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During your initial declaration of `out` you can put in `<th>` or tableheader tags, i.e:

```
    function renderSearchResults( results, domNode ) {
       var i;
       var out = "<table><th>ContractId</th><th>ContractTitle</th><th>Terminal</th><th>Cabinet </th><th>Section </th><th>Folder </th><th>Sheet </th><th>Consult </th><th>Location </th><th>Active </th><th>Theme </th><th>Construction </th><th>Subtheme </th><th>AsBuilt </th><th>Year </th>";

       if (results.length === 0) {
          domNode.innerHTML = 'No results matching your search.';
          return;
       }

       results.forEach(function (result) {
        console.info(result);
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        (result.ContractId !== null ? result.ContractId : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.ContractTitle !== null ? result.ContractTitle : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Terminal !== null ? result.Terminal : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Cabinet !== null ? result.Cabinet : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Section !== null ? result.Section : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Folder !== null ? result.Folder : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Sheet !== null ? result.Sheet : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Consult !== null ? result.Consult : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Location !== null ? result.Location : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Active !== null ? result.Active : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Theme !== null ? result.Theme : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Construction !== null ? result.Construction : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Subtheme !== null ? result.Subtheme : 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.AsBuilt !== null ? result.AsBuilt: 'Not Applicable') +
        "</td><td>" +
        (result.Year !== null ? result.Year : 'Not Applicable')+
        "</td><td>" +
        "<a href= " + result.Path + " target=_blank>" + "Binder" + "</a>"
    } );

        out += "</table>";
        console.log(out);
       domNode.innerHTML = out;
   }
```

Comment: He forgot to add the `<tr>` tag, with that should work

Comment: I thought `<th>` tags can stand alone but I wonder if the OP is looking for a heading for each individual table row?

Comment: still doesnt work. i need just one header for the whole table tho. not multiple.

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the function call as I thought it should be.  You don't see anything different when you make the out declaration change?  Perhaps you can set a `console.log(out)` at the end and let us know what you see?

Comment: ^_^ i dont know how to work with console yet. can you tell me the steps, pls?

Comment: Oh, if your looking at your page on chrome, right click and hit inspect and that should open the console log (you might need to click the console tab). I've added the `console.log(out);` call in my answer.

Comment: cool, thanks! i did that and now i should look for something there? ^_^

Comment: If the `console.log(out)` was called you should see a html version of your table.  In interested to see if the table headers are there.

Comment: yes, i see it there and also see the header now. i forgot to save my .js file. :P  THANK YOU! :)

Comment: can i ask you one more question?

Comment: Sure can, Go for it!

Comment: how can i replace the null values for each of the cells of my table with a string value like 'n/a' or 'not specified'?

Comment: I've updated my answer but what I'm using is the shorthand form of if else. If the field is not null set it to it's value otherwise set it to not applicable

Answer (score 0):

There is a different tag for the table header.

`<tr>` is for row `<th>` for your headers and `<td>` for the data.

You can check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) for more info.

You can either add your header after your check for results:

```
if (results.length === 0) {
        domNode.innerHTML = 'No results matching your search.';
        return;
} else {
   out += "<tr><th>Header</th></tr>"
}
```

Comment: what do you mean? <th> tag? my problem is that i cant include it here in my JS code. because it loops and add a header before each row.

Comment: You can add that prior to the loop, as the else statement you aren't using.

Comment: You're welcome, but upvotes are better than tanks :p. You should upvote anything you find useful, so at least Sweet_Pete should get +1

Comment: i did but my reputation is less that 15 so it doesn't show but it says that it counts! :)